# Tensorflow: How to initlialize all variables in a given variable scope

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow

I want to initlialize all variables in a given variable scope, is there any other method than just listing all the names of variables?
Variables in the scope are already created but not initialized,only initlialization needs to be done

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of variables in your scope with

```
my_scope = 'my_scope_name'
scope_variables=  tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES, scope=my_scope )
```

and then initialize them with

```
init_scope = tf.variables_initializer(scope_variables, name="init_"+my_scope )
sess.run(init_scope)
```